# Material UI Select component not displaying properly

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I have created a simple select component with menu items (material ui v 4.12). But the select component is being displayed entirely wrong. There are no console errors. What might be wrong here?

Here is the screenshot and the code.

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const mockData = ["list01", "list02"];

function TestPage() {
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    formControl: {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      minWidth: 120,
    },
    selectEmpty: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  }));
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [data, setData] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="test">
      <h2>TEST</h2>
      <FormControl
        variant="outlined"
        classes={{
          root: classes.formControl,
        }}
      >
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">
          Select list
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          id="test-select-outlined"
          value={data}
          onChange={(e) => setData(e.target.value)}
          label="Select list"
        >
          {mockData.map((item, index) => (
            <MenuItem key={index + 1} value={item}>
              {item}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TestPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Select` import is wrong:

```js
import Select from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
```

just change it to:

```js
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
```